# find the actual mean from "noisy data"

Tags: mean

Case: A team is estimating the amount of work they have planned to do for the next week. There are 4-5 items each week and each individual item is estimated to be between 1 and 20 units of work. The team is afraid of under-estimating, so they have a tendency to pad the estimates with safety. In X% of the cases, they manage to complete all work items and in the cases where they didn't need all of the safety, they still use it (Student's syndrome).
Based on this data and all the assumptions needed such as the actual sizes of the work items being normally distribution and that half of the estimates without safety are too low and half of the estimates are too high but the average is just right. Would it be possible to create a function of X (the percentage they complete everything on time) and the amount of safety they were likely putting in?

Comment: Yes.  You should provide dummy data and have someone step you through what a reasonable approach would be.

Comment: I don't think this question is answerable.  The reason is that under your assumptions, when half the estimates are too high and half are too low and the average is just right, you may conclude that the padded estimates are *unbiased.* Thus, the original estimation procedure was biased low and the safety factor was exactly what was needed to remove that bias.  However, it's impossible to determine the *amount* of bias: all we can say is that it has been corrected. Mathematically, you are asking us to solve the equation $(1/x)\times x = 1$ for $x.$

Comment: @whuber thanks for the comment. I guess I didn't express myself clearly enough. With "just right" I meant unbiased as well. That is the unpadded average would be what a crystal ball would have shown us. The estimates are of course biased but in the two scenarios I'll be contrasting I can assume that the bias is the same in both cases and all I'm interested in, is how changing X would affect the padding

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some more assumptions on this, such as an upper bound on the number of units of work that can be completed and how the safety is applied (a percentage of work units?). But once you have those, in general, you should be able to just take the difference between the distribution of the number of units of work expended (say, 40 per week) and the distribution of the number of units of work required (4-5 items per week * 1-20 units of work, ~ normal distribution). The difference would give you the distribution of the safety applied, after you account for whatever other assumptions are pertinent (only X% of items get completed, half of estimates without safety too low, half too high, etc.).

Comment: Not sure I understand. I know how many work items are completed. They are estimated with some safety. I do not know the safety/padding. and thus I don't know how many could have been completed. Assuming a normal distribution of the estimates and an average 0f 4.5 items pr week, wouldn't that result in 4,5 * 10,5 units of work on average?

Comment: Sorry, I thought the 1-20 was the actual amount of work required. Without that information, I agree with whuber: whether the work got completed or not wouldn’t tell you anything about the distribution of the safety – it would just be normal variation. You’d need to make some different assumptions to get at safety.